# Can I higlight brackets / parenthesis pairings by clicking on them in Textmate?

Tags: macos, text-editor, textmate

I recently started using Textmate, and I am loving it. I come from Notepad ++, and there is only one thing I miss: the ability to click on a bracket or parenthesis and highlighting the opening and closing pair.

I know you can see the pairings of a bracket or parenthesis with a keyboard shortcut (command + option + B, I think), but clicking on them is much more faster and convenient. Given that the software has this feature, I thought there must be a setting for enabling click highlighting, but I cant seem to find it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to enable this?

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to make that work! Just auto highlighting is the most efficient way to find the beginning/end of a block...

Comment: @Johe Yes, it would be great. I posted the question to superuser and offered a bounty, but no one has replied yet... I will post the solution here if someone knows it

Answer (score 1):

Use code folding. Select menu item View/Gutter/Foldings. Click on the little triangle in the border on the left of the window (next to the line number in you also selected View/Gutter/Line Numbers).

Comment: Thank you Doug. I found it very strange that Textmate didnt have that option. Great! I will try it when I get home

Comment: I just tried this, and although it is useful, it is not exactly what I was looking for... I want to be able to highlight pairings of brackets / parentheses just by clicking of them, which i find quicker / more useful than collapsing them, any more ideas?